# Currently using BeatifulSoup to check the links on a webpage. Not getting any status codes for the links?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

#### Setup:

```py
site = 'https://www.benefits.gov'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 
10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 
Safari/537.36'}
base = urlparse(site).netloc
print('test')
to_visit = [site]
outlinks = []
visited = {}
external_visited = {}
```

#### Site to visit:

```py
while to_visit:
    l = to_visit.pop()
    print(l)
    url = urljoin(site, l)
    print('test1')

    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        visited[l] = r.status_code
        print("test5")
    except:
        visited[l] = None
        print('test2')

    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("test6")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
        print("test7")
        links = [l['href'] for l in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
        for link in links:
            parsed_link = urlparse(link)
            loc = parsed_link.netloc
            path = parsed_link.path
            joined_url = urljoin(site, link)
            print('test3')

            if loc == '':
                print("test9")
                if joined_url not in to_visit and joined_url not in visited.keys():
                    to_visit.append(joined_url)

            elif loc == base:
                if link not in to_visit and link not in visited.keys():
                    to_visit.append(link)

            else:
                if link not in outlinks and link not in visited.keys():
                    outlinks.append(link)
                    print('test4')
```

#### Check external link status:

```py
while outlinks:
    l = outlinks.pop()
    print("test8")
    try:
        r = requests.get(l)
        external_visited[l] = r.status_code

    except:
        external_visited[l] = None
```

Comment: all of this is code except the bold text. Don't know why the formating looks like this

Comment: Something is triggering your exception and setting the status code value to None. I suggest putting it like this to read the exception: `except Exception as e: print(e)`. It's possible that the link is already an absolute link, so you're creating urls like this `https://web.site/https://absolutelink.site/test.html` and the url is not accessible so it raises an exception.

Comment: hmm let me try fixing something